# The "such" in "such type of plants" and "such a person"?

Tags: word-usage, usage, adverbs, adjectives

I know that I can say "such type of plants" instead of "such a type of plants", but why cannot I say "such person" instead of "such a person"?

Is there any reason for these two different usages of "such"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can (correctly) say "such type of plants". I believe the difference is singular vs. plural. When you're using the singular (person, plant), include 'a': "Such a person", "Such a type of plants" (In this case 'type of plants' is a singular, the plural would be 'types of plants').

When the subject is plural, you leave out 'a': "Such people", "Such types of plants".

Comment: Clear; much appreciated! I see. I was under a wrong impression that "such type" is a legitimate usage. :)

Comment: I agree. "Such type" does not sound correct. "Such a type" could be correct, but is not commonly used.

Comment: I would interpret "such type of plants" to mean "such plants (of that type)", NOT "such a type of plants".